# Direct sum of a group and generator

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

When talking of a group $G$ being the direct sum of a set of subgroups $\{H_i\}$, the following part is a part of definition (from wiki): $G$ is generated by the subgroups $\{H_i\}$

So, does this mean that the generator set is $\{H_1, H_2, H_3, H_4..\}$? Or does the set consist of just elements of the subgroups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is meant that $G$ is the smallest group containing all the $H_{i}$. A generator set would be $H_{1} \cup H_{2} \cup \dots $, as per your second option. A smaller generator set can be obtained as the union of generator sets for the various $H_{i}$.